# PHP Form-Value Echoing Misunderstanding

Tags: php, forms, post, foreach, echo

I have a form that I'm creating which upon filling it out and clicking the submit button the entered information will be echoed below. It works; however, the submit button is getting used as a field, and I'm unsure why (meaning the submit button & its value is being echoed) Some help would be appreciated.

**My code is as follows**

```
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Friend Information</legend>
                <form action="inclass6.php" method="post">
                    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" /><br/>

                    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" value=""/><br/>

                    <label for="phone_number">Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone_number" value=""/><br/>

                    <label for="age">Age</label>
                    <input type="number" name="age" value=""/><br/>

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_button" id="submit_button" />
                </form>
            </fieldset>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan=2>Submitted Info</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Field</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $output = fopen("output.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");

                    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                        if($value != "Submit"){
                            fwrite($output, $value);
                            if($key != "age"){
                                fwrite($output, ", ");
                            }
                        }

                        echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>$value</td></tr>\n";
                    }

                    fwrite($output, "\n");
                    fclose($myfile);
                ?>
            </table>
```

Comment: the solution is simple, use a button with a submit type with no value.

Comment: @Fred-ii- do you mean to say something along the lines of this:

<input type="submit" value="" name="submit_button" id="submit_button" />
...? Because 1. this would leave the button without text, and 2. this doesn't fix my problem. For some reason, the if-statement that says "if($value != "Submit") is not working as intended. Everything with no value is SUPPOSED to get echoed, whereas the button with the value of "Submit" is not.

Comment: No ,this `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` instead of your `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_button" id="submit_button" />`

Comment: Ahhhh, I understand now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'll post an answer then, welcome.

Comment: I've posted it below if you wish to mark it as solved, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments:

Use a button with a submit type containing no value.

`<button type="submit">Submit</button>`

instead of your

`<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_button" id="submit_button" />`